# Docker HTML publishing

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a simple HTML file(just normal coding nothing special), now my question or help is that I want to publish this/run this HTML file through docker images and containers only.
Kindly please help me out through it.....

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this article: https://serversforhackers.com/getting-started-with-docker/ or this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerizing/
All you need is a container configured as a web server.

Comment: Something like an NGINX image is an easy way to start: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/